# python - split list of dictionaries into multiple lists of dictionaries, without grouping

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I'm trying to split a list of dictionaries by two key/values into multiple lists. The original list of dictionaries is pulled from an app that is slow to return data (3rd party) so I've avoided making multiple calls and am now am getting all the data I need in one query. however, I now need to split this data into groups matching NodeIDs and Names whilst maintaining the original data

sample data:

```
[{'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555526, 'OutAveragebps': 64.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:10:00.0000000'
},
{'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.04555526, 'OutAveragebps': 6456.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:11:00.0000000'
},
{'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03554479, 'OutAveragebps': 64.7012558, 'DateTime': '2018-05-16T01:01:00.0000000'
},
{'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555063, 'OutAveragebps': 64.62538, 'DateTime': '2018-05-17T01:011:00.0000000'
}]
```

so the put would then have two lists as such:

```
[{'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555526, 'OutAveragebps': 64.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:10:00.0000000'
},
{'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.04555526, 'OutAveragebps': 6456.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:11:00.0000000'
}],[
{'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03554479, 'OutAveragebps': 64.7012558, 'DateTime': '2018-05-16T01:01:00.0000000'
},
{'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555063, 'OutAveragebps': 64.62538, 'DateTime': '2018-05-17T01:011:00.0000000'
}]
```

I've tried using itertools, collections:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

interface_data = []
grouper = itemgetter("NodeID", "Name")
for key,v in groupby(sorted(results, key = grouper), grouper):
    temp_dict = dict(zip(["NodeID", "Name"], key))
    interface_data.append(temp_dict)
```

collections

```
from collections import defaultdict
interface_data = defaultdict(list)
for i in results:
     interface_data[(i['NodeID'],i['InterfaceName'])].append(i)
```

I'm not getting anywhere at the moment which is frustrating considering how simple this seems to be.

Comment: What result / error does your code produce?

Comment: Would you consider using a nested dict instead? E.g., the NodeID would be the key for easy lookup, and the value would be the list of elements with that ID?

Comment: "I'm not getting anywhere at the moment" is not a problem statement. Surely you have some specific symptoms of "not getting anywhere" you'd like to share and discuss?

Comment: While you're at it, please indent your second snippet properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a nested dictionary with `defaultdict`, then call `list()` on its values:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> interface_data = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in s:
...     key = i['NodeID'], i['Name']
...     interface_data[key].append(i)

>>> list(interface_data.values())
[[{'NodeID': 1563,
   'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1',
   'InAveragebps': 0.03555526,
   'OutAveragebps': 64.50593,
   'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:10:00.0000000'},
  {'NodeID': 1563,
   'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1',
   'InAveragebps': 0.04555526,
   'OutAveragebps': 6456.50593,
   'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:11:00.0000000'}],
 [{'NodeID': 1788,
   'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2',
   'InAveragebps': 0.03554479,
   'OutAveragebps': 64.7012558,
   'DateTime': '2018-05-16T01:01:00.0000000'},
  {'NodeID': 1788,
   'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2',
   'InAveragebps': 0.03555063,
   'OutAveragebps': 64.62538,
   'DateTime': '2018-05-17T01:011:00.0000000'}]]
```

It is perhaps a bit of a roundabout way to get back to a list result, but ultimately you want to do some type of membership testing (or, more like a lookup, in this case), and a dictionary is well-suited for that in the first place.

Before calling `list()`, `interface_data` is a nested dictionary; its keys are 2-tuples of (NodeID, Name) and its values are the dictionaries themselves.

```
>>> interface_data.keys()
dict_keys([(1563, 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1'), (1788, 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2')])
```

Comment: so using a collection I could select a specific list group?

Comment: Well yes, if that's your ultimate purpose, perhaps you want to retain as a nested defaultdict?

Comment: id want to be able to select only list 1 (using id and interface) or any n list depending on them. also what is s in your sample? when I currently run this in shell I get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: `s` is the sample data exactly as you have it in your question

Comment: thank, how would I then just get the list with ID 1563 and GigabitEthernet1/1/1 only?

Comment: `interface_data[(1563, 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1')]` where `interface_data` is the defaultdict

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, `itertools.groupby` is quite simple, as only the `'NodeId'` is used as the grouping key:

```
import itertools
d = [{'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555526, 'OutAveragebps': 64.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:10:00.0000000'}, {'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.04555526, 'OutAveragebps': 6456.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:11:00.0000000'}, {'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03554479, 'OutAveragebps': 64.7012558, 'DateTime': '2018-05-16T01:01:00.0000000'}, {'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555063, 'OutAveragebps': 64.62538, 'DateTime': '2018-05-17T01:011:00.0000000'}]
final_result = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(d, key=lambda x:x['NodeID'])]
```

Output:

```
[[{'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555526, 'OutAveragebps': 64.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:10:00.0000000'}, {'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.04555526, 'OutAveragebps': 6456.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:11:00.0000000'}], [{'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03554479, 'OutAveragebps': 64.7012558, 'DateTime': '2018-05-16T01:01:00.0000000'}, {'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555063, 'OutAveragebps': 64.62538, 'DateTime': '2018-05-17T01:011:00.0000000'}]]
```

Edit:

If your data is not guaranteed to be sorted by `id`, `sorted` must be applied:

```
final_result = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x['NodeID']), key=lambda x:x['NodeID'])]
```

Comment: Depending on how the data is populated, sorting may be required before the `groupby`

Comment: in that case of unordered data `groupby` loses some interest, and defaultdict is the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution using `itertools.groupby` is already quite close, but instead of appending `key`, you should append `v` after converting it to a list instead:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

interface_data = []
grouper = itemgetter("NodeID", "Name")
for _, v in groupby(sorted(results, key = grouper), grouper):
    interface_data.append(list(v))
print(interface_data)
```

This outputs:

```
[[{'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555526, 'OutAveragebps': 64.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:10:00.0000000'}, {'NodeID': 1563, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet1/1/1', 'InAveragebps': 0.04555526, 'OutAveragebps': 6456.50593, 'DateTime': '2018-05-29T01:11:00.0000000'}], [{'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03554479, 'OutAveragebps': 64.7012558, 'DateTime': '2018-05-16T01:01:00.0000000'}, {'NodeID': 1788, 'Name': 'GigabitEthernet2/1/2', 'InAveragebps': 0.03555063, 'OutAveragebps': 64.62538, 'DateTime': '2018-05-17T01:011:00.0000000'}]]
```